# dropdown navigation with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a navigation system but the drop down is not working.
I am using jquery to make the dropdown animation but when I press home nothing happens here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Home").click(function() {
    $("#Games").SlideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="Navigation">

    <ul id="Games">
      <a id="Home" href="#">Home</a>
      <li>CS:GO</li>
      <li>Call Of Duty</li>
      <li>Clash of Clans</li>
      <li>Dungeons and Dragons</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `slideToggle` not `SlideToggle`. JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. Some basic debugging with your browser's console would've shown you the error.

Comment: not related to the problem, but shouldn't the link to be outside of the ul element?

Comment: the problem is still present

Comment: What problem is still present? Oh btw, I also neglected to add that your HTML is invalid. You can't have an `<a>` as a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: @Ataxfundedreligion add li with $('#Games li').slideToggle();
[ https://jsfiddle.net/jq5haj4w/1/ ] And btw if you want to hide those li before click  you can add a css #Games li{  display:none; }

Comment: When working with links you should consider to add `event.preventDefault()` inside the event handler if the link should not do anything

Comment: @MostafaBaezid You cannot edit a question and remove the very cause of the problem.

Comment: @j08691 hey sorry i added my fiddle jQuery  by mistake. Sorry

Comment: Folks, please just vote to close this question as off-topic due to a typo

Answer (score 0):

The command is `slideToggle()`. Use like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/chzvk4wq/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Home").click(function() {
    $("#Games").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: The other thing you didn't mention is the html markup you changed

Comment: @empiric it was seen in the example, yet not as relevant to the answer. Also I did not want to presume I understand what OP wanted to do with his HTML. Also it was already commented upon.